# Is there a term to describe when you reject someones forgiveness?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests

Let's say someone says they forgive you for something you did, but you don't believe you did anything wrong that needs forgiving. Is there a term to describe that? Rejecting someone's forgiveness? (Forgiveness not apology).

Comment: Can you explain why the straightforward *I reject your forgiveness, I did nothing wrong* is not a satisfactory answer to your question?  Are there shades of meaning which you are searching to incorporate and which it fails to express?

Comment: Yes, *rejecting* or *not accepting* would appear the usual terms for both forgiveness and apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that person is in denial.

Here's the explanation of denial from merriam-webster.com, and I think it fits the criteria of what you are looking for.

> 1. Refusal to satisfy a request or desire.
> 2. Refusal to admit the truth or reality of something (such as a statement or charge).
> 3. Assertion that an allegation is false.
> 4. Refusal to acknowledge a person or a thing.
> 5. In law: The opposing by the defendant of an allegation.
> 6. In psychology: A defense mechanism in which confrontation with a personal problem or with reality is avoided by denying the existence of the problem or reality.
> 7. (Phrases) In denial: Refusing to admit the truth or reality of something unpleasant.

Read more of explanations of denial here:

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Denial

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).